# How to prevent new line caused by \\n in %WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Is there a way that I can prevent the new line caused by '\n' in:

```
%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe
```

I want to show this string in a html page and I use javascript to show it. However, I get:

```
 %WINDIR%\system32 etsh.exe
```

Also, I get this string using a python template and I already tried to replace it  with various combinations of '\', '/', and 'n' in python and still no luck!

I appreciate if someone can provide some hint.

Comment: Have you tried prepending your string with an `r`? As in, instead of `'%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe'`, using `r'%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe'`?

Comment: Exactly how are you using javascript to show this? And how are you using python? Can we get a MCVE?

Comment: Using pure js to show that string doesn't seem to have an issue: https://jsfiddle.net/6tqd530f/1/ so how do you "use javascript to show it"?

Comment: @PMende that's interesting, but still it can't get it solved. It seems the issue is in js part.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Python handles a json object that will be passed to a template. This template uses d3 library in javascript and I need to show some node info using the text I get from python. Excuse me that it's not MCVE!

Comment: @Likak I asked for a MCVE because I can't reproduce the problem you're reporting. Since I can't reproduce the problem, I have **no idea** how you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of: first is what I recommended in my comment: prepending your string with an r. So using `r'%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe'`, instead of `'%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe'`.

Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you can try using `pathlib`. Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path_str = str(Path('%WINDIR%\\system32\\netsh.exe'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

```
var text = "%WINDIR%\\\\system32\\\\netsh.exe";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
```